# Prove using induction on the number of elements in $A$ that $maxA$ and $minA$.

Tags: real-analysis

> If  $$\emptyset ≠ A \subseteq R $$
> is a finite set.
> Prove using induction on the number of elements in $A$ that $maxA$ and
> $minA$ exist.

Hello everyone, this is my first question on the forum, sorry if I'm wrong.
I know about induction but I can't figure out how to apply it on the question. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Yes, I apologize. The question states that $A$ is a finite set.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you written down the base case?

Comment: I can't think of anything. In fact, what we have done for this question is more inductive definition than inductive proof. If we go through the inductive "proof", perhaps as a base step we can consider that the set A has a single element. I'm really confused.

Comment: For the base case think about what the set $A$ looks like and what it's $\max$ and $\min$ might be. For the inductive step think about adding an extra element to a finite set. What are the possible ways it relates to other elements in the set?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
in the base step, if there is an element in the set, $maxA$ is that element (I don't know how to express it mathematically).

and for each new element added, the following comparison is made: $maxA = max(maxA, "new element")$

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I think the answer is clear in my mind. But I still need confirmation ._.

## Base Step

If the set $A$ has 1 element, then that element is both $maxA$ and $minA$.

## Induction Step

Suppose $maxA$ and $minA$ are defined for every set $A$ with $k$ elements. Now we need to prove that the set $A$ with $k+1$ elements also has $max(A)$ and $min(A)$.

The set $A$ now has $k+1$ elements. Let's remove a random element $x$ from the set. We know that any set $A'$ with $k$ elements has a maximum and minimum. Let us call these numbers $maxA'$ and $minA'$.

Now we need to add our $x$ element to the list and compare the states.

If $x ≤ maxA'$ then $maxA = maxA'$
If $x > maxA'$ then $maxA = x$

A similar comparison can be made for $min$.

I think this is correct, thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: Solid proof.  Only improvement I could see is maybe being a little more precise with your wording i.e. "Let $x\in A$ be given. Then $A-\{x\}$ has $k$ elements, and thus $min (A-\{x\})$ and $max(A-\{x\})$ exist." I'm making a couple other edits, if you don't mind.

Comment: Yes I really needed a formal proof. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's a good proof. More precise wording will come through time and experience. I think you could make it a bit more compact by leaving out the part of removing an element, and instead just start with sets of size $k$ and adding an element. But you should definitely accept it as a correct answer when you can.

Comment: @JacobWalker Thank you so much